# How to transition drywall to cabinet at pony wall?

Tags: drywall, walls, transition

I am drywalling the end of a pony wall that meets a kitchen cabinet. What is the best way to make this transition? The cabinet is ~1/4" recessed from the stud face, and currently has a piece of scribe moulding that butted up to the original drywall sort of like this - [image].

I'm trying for a more minimalist look:

- Tearaway L-bead or J-bead the drywall to the scribe moulding?
- Route/plane the stud down so that the drywall ends up flush with the
  cabinet?
- Is there a better way to make a flush/semi-flush look?

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: To be clear, the upper is vaguely like and the lower is what you actually have?  They clearly are not the same.

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes, lower picture is what exists now. Upper is similar to what it was before.

Comment: How much overhang do you have on the top?

Answer (score 1):

Buy an end panel from the cabinetry company in the same color as the cabients. 30" should do. That allows you to cover the end of the ponywall and cabinet in one clean plane.

Answer (score 0):

Flush is not usually a good plan. It's very difficult to get things perfectly on plane, and then you have a joint to deal with anyway.

I would build out the framing and wrap it with drywall in the usual manner for a standard, inconspicuous appearance. Leave at least 1" of overhang when finished. A J-bead seems like a good solution at the cabinet. Put some masking tape on the cabinet as you work.